# Java - Supress Do you want to run this application?

Tags: java, java-web-start

We have a web application that uses Java and every time the website is loaded the user gets a Java popup stating "Do you want to run this application" The application will run with unrestricted access etc....

Is there a way to prevent this popup from happening? We are using Java 8 Update 131 and I haven't seen where I can suppress this message box. I see the older versions had an exceptions site list but I don't think you can do it with the newer java versions. Anyone have any suggestions on how to prevent this Java run box from popping up? TIA

Comment: Do you mean an applet?

Comment: Its just a website that loads the local java. Its similar to the image here https://techhelpkb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/do-you-want-to-run-this-application-java2.png

Comment: Is that Java Webstart?

Comment: Im not sure, that's just the message we are getting that we would like to suppress. The website was developed externally and I am tasked to get rid of that popup and let the java run anyway

Comment: Well, good luck!

Comment: [This Article](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4022270) might help.  The gist is "One final setting can be used to customize the user experience in Java Web Start. By default the sandbox does not include the AWTPermissionshowWindowWithoutWarningBanner. Without this permission, all top-level windows will contain the awt banner "Java Application Window" or "Java Applet Window". The deployment configuration property deployment.security.sandbox.awtwarningwindow can be used to add this permission to untrusted code."

Comment: Ran out of room so also linked [article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/client-security.html) may help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the pop up is preventable in this website. I think that the computer is just letting you know that the application you are trying to run may be too advanced for the website to handle. It may not be running on version 8.